# How to select a object by function?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I would like to select a object by run function instead of by mouse click. But I couldn't find the function from the docs for Fabric JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`js
canvas.setActiveObject();`

can't work in 2.0.0-beta.4 ,I solved it by change the version to 1.7.17.

Comment: its working with 2.0.0-beta6, check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/ax5mw5L1/1/). and dont put this as answer. You can add this in your question or as a comment to your question.